# URL Rewrite/Mod Rewrite .htaccess on Apache and PHP

Tags: php, apache, url-rewriting

I have a single point of entry on my website

`mysite.com/admin/index.php?View=List&Model=User`

All access to the DB/application is through this index.php file.

I would like to clean my URL from what is shown above to.

`mysite.com/admin/List/User`

The idea is to remove the key 'Model and 'View'.

I have found this link that looks very similar.

[PHP/Apache: Rewrite rules with .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6982235/php-apache-rewrite-rules-with-htaccess)

Comment: None of the options seem to work. I have a feeling Im missing a module

Comment: LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so is enabled, are there Any more modules that need to be enabled ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in htaccess file insert this code :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^admin/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /admin/index.php?View=$1&Model=$2 [L]
```

The rewritten URL:

```
http://mysite.com/admin/List/User
```

this site very useful for generate rewrite URL

http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/

Answer (score 1):

Create a file named .htaccess in your web root if you haven't already got one with the following:

```
# Turn the rewrite engine on (skip this if already done)
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect admin/List/User/ to admin/index.php?View=List&Model=User
RewriteRule ^admin/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ admin/index.php?View=$1&Model=$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^admin/([^/]+)/([^/]+) /index.php?View=$1&Model=$2 [NC]
```

Add to .htaccess in the root folder of your website.