# How to make a profile like url ?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, seo

I have a project I want to make a friendly url.

I have a user *Beraki*

I made a part like this website.com/beraki

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ profile.php?username=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ profile.php?username=$1
```

Working Perfect

I want to do something like this

**website.com/beraki/about

website.com/beraki/photos

website.com/beraki/friends**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9159949/url-rewrite-mod-rewrite-htaccess-on-apache-and-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On

# Optional '/' sign can be simplified with '?'
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_-]+)/?$ profile.php?username=$1                  [NC,L]

# If you want to specify your list of valid parts after each username:
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_-]+)/(about|photos|friends)$ profile.php?username=$1&page=$2      [NC,L]

# If you want regex for the part after username:
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_-]+)/(a-z)$ profile.php?username=$1&page=$2    [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this [generator](http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/).This generator can help you.Simple and easy :)

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /?username=$1&link=$2 [L]
```

Link is name of page.For example:about,options etc..
If you want to acces about page of profile.

> website.com/?username=Beraki&link=about --> website.com/Beraki/about

Comment: Not a constructive answer, this should be a comment.

Comment: I know but,i can't comment,look at my reputation.

Comment: @DarylGill do u have a constructive one ?