# Url RewriteRule with php not able get the path

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am creating a shopping website and i want to show categories category/parentcat/subcat/categoryno. I have created a function in php for generating category url but i am not able to redirect them to current source.

I have url

```
http://www.mydomain.com?catgory.php?cat_id=1
```

I want to change it

```
http://www.mydomain.com/whatever/whatever/1.html
```

How can i do it with .htacess file.
I have already read whats here [URL Rewrite/Mod Rewrite .htaccess on Apache and PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9159949/url-rewrite-mod-rewrite-htaccess-on-apache-and-php) but my question a bit different becuase i am just passing a single parameter cat_id and example show it with two that i can understand.

Comment: Are you using any frameworks like Zend or Symfony?

Comment: @CBergau , no i not using any framework its just custom code

Comment: @harke
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^category/[^/]+/([0-9]+)/[^/]+\.html$ category.php?cat_id=$1 

</IfModule>  here is what i was looking for