# I need on the apache2.conf a <Directory> that hides .php extensions

Tags: php, regex, apache

I'm using a virtual machine to emulate an apache server (linux debian), and I can't manage to hide the .php file extension on the website's URL.

I'm modifying the apache2.conf in /etc/apache2/apache.conf instead of adding a .htaccess file because Apache suggests to do so.

I currently have:

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    RewriteEngine On
    Options FollowSymLinks
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php !-f
    RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
</Directory>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [URL Rewrite/Mod Rewrite .htaccess on Apache and PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9159949/url-rewrite-mod-rewrite-htaccess-on-apache-and-php)

Comment: No, it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use `.htaccess` in directories where you want to run php files without extension.

---

Depends on the version of your PHP engine, add the following lines:

#### PHP 7.0

```
<FilesMatch '^[^.]+$'>
  SetHandler application/x-httpd-php70
</FilesMatch>
```

#### PHP 7.0 Single

```
<FilesMatch '^[^.]+$'>
  SetHandler application/x-httpd-php70s
</FilesMatch>
```

#### PHP 7.0 FastCGI

```
<FilesMatch '^[^.]+$'>
  SetHandler fcgid70-script
</FilesMatch>
```

---

Don't forget to remove the `.php` extension from such files in those directories.

Comment: Why do you suggest using .htaccess? If your reasons are valid then why is Apache saying we shouldn't?

Comment: Because rewrite rules won't prevent using links with the extension, they will create just alternative links (aliases) to those full paths that includes `.php` at the end.